# Is It possible to skip the switching of certain weapons

Tags: team-fortress-2

I saw this one video by  [Uncle Dane](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCu0PSyLD5p_J5osLk5UD0pw)  in which he shows that through scripting he was able to make it so that when switching weapons by scrolling the wheel,(as an engineer) the PDAs do not open(build and destroy), it directly goes to the melee or the primary weapon. How is this done?

Comment: If the question is not very clear, please change to something appropriate. I was not able to think up of what else I should put up as the heading.

Comment: Hi Jawwad, I'm pretty sure that question is what you're asking, if not let me know and we can clarify the question and remove the duplicate closure. :-)

Comment: yes, that is the question I am asking. Thanks for notifying me.